# get parent node of treeview node

Tags: delphi, firebird

There are 'Accounts' table in firebird db where are stored:

Acc_id- unique, integer, not null, primary key,
Acc_num- unique,varchar(30)
Prnt_id- integer
Acc_Title- description,text explanation

```
 Acc_id   Acc_num   Prnt_id   Acc_Title

  0       Base       Null     Base account  
  1       1000       0        Current assets account
  2       1100       1        some text    
  3       1110       2        some text
  4       1110 1     3        some text
  5       1110 1 15  4        some text
  6       2000       0        some text
  7       2700       6        some text
  8       1110 1 16  4        some text
  ...
  101     1155 1     1155     some text
  102     1125       1100     some text
```

For example, I must insert record of account 2700 in db. In edit control I enter account number 2700 and must find out that his parent is account 2000 (parent_id=6).
How to find out with firebird-sql that account 2000 is parent of account 2700 or 1120 is parent of 1125 etc?

If I **by error** stay on 1000 or 1100 or 1110 account and want to create account 1125 **sql-query must guess that parent is account 1100 and must add as child of 1100 account**, not in 1000 or 1110.

[image]

Comment: Well, from here it looks like you should search for Trunc(Acc_id/10)*10, if not found try with 100, if not with 1000. But it's really your database, you should be the one to know the specs.

Comment: Discard my comment, the "1155 1", etc. does not fit. You should consult with the documentation, programmer, ... whom else is responsible with the design.

Comment: @ Sertac Akyuz, it's not from my db. It is international accounts tree. Such trees are used in many apps in my country.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask about specifications of an account tree.

Comment: How is the definition of the ```parent``` of an account number? In your example 2000 is the parent for 2700. But what if 2000 does not exist? Based on your tree, what would be the parent for 2850 or 1112?

Comment: Edit question and add the table data that would have listed all the columns for the accounts 2000, 2700, 1120, 1125

Comment: @Arioch 'The, I have edited post.

Comment: @basti - BTW by your description, `acc_num` column may contain multiple NULL rows.

Comment: @basti `I must insert record of account 2700 in db` - into which table? there ALREADY is the row `7/2700/6` in the `Accounts` table. You can not insert 2700 into `Accounts` twice, can you ?

Comment: Arioch 'The, I can insert the the row 7/2700/6 in account table only once. Acc_num field is unique. I don't understand you question.

Comment: Arioch 'The, As I see, it's very difficult and strange way create such accounts tree. Then I will change acc-num field structure to save numbers like this: 1000-0001, 1000-0002. 2000-0000, 2700-0000. Then everything will be much more easy.  Thank you.

Comment: When you write "I must insert record of account 2700 in db" - into which table of many "in db" do you insert ???  You write sample data when "2700" is already in the db in the Accounts table. Then you write "i must insert 2700" but it is already there in your sample data. There is a contradiction for me as whether what you gonna do in what a situation. So I can either try guessing (and guessing wrongly) or ask you for tedious but detailed and consistent description of the situation.

Comment: Also, in general, "sql-query must guess that parent is account 1100" - is a very bad approach. It is close to "indeterminate behavior". Basically there is a binary choice: either your program (and I mean the whole system, Delphi-written, firebird-written and rest, taken all-together) DOES KNOW the parent, or it DOES NOT. If it DOES - it should not ask ever user for it. Humans are unreliably erring, and it also wastes human's time. If the program DOES NOT know - then it should not be GUESSING. Worse so, it should not do it secretly, faking user-inputted data without notifying user.

Comment: "If I by error stay on 1000 or 1100 or 1110" - so you mean the Delphi written program, that has the tree on the screenshot. BTW, is it Windows standard slow `TTreeView` - or fast `TVirtualStringTree` from VTV package? Back to the topic. If your program CAN determine the parent just by the title entered, it SHOULD always do it and should not ever check which item is user-selected in the tree. More so, when the user is typing the title number via `TEdit.OnChange` your program should be trying to find parent to new entered name and instantly display it write above or below the name user is typing

Comment: This way user would instantly see if new name he is typing (and whatching closely  the name's TEdit and not watching other parts of the window) makes sense for the program, and if the program correctly deduces the parent intended - or not. Now, when the program is guessing the parent name - it actually is one way or another finding the parent data variable (object, record, index in array - whatever). From that variable you take BOTH the title to show for the user right above the `TEdit` and the parent's `acc_id`. When ur prog finally issues the SQL insertion, it already knows parent's ID

Answer (score 0):

You again tell next about nothing about your problem. You'd have to show sample data as a short extract form your table! So we can only try to guess what you mean and if we would guess wrong, then bad luck.

- Assuming (guessing) that values like "1200" are stored in `VARCHAR` column `Title` - and not for example in `Acc_number`,
- Assuming that titles are unique (and they may be not unique, if you did not enriched SQL table with the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `UNIQUE INDEX` on that `Title` field,
- Assuming that there is an `index` on that field (otherwise it would be very slow), and also on `acc_id` field and on `parent_id` field,

Your query would look something like this:

```
Select t1.* 
from MyTable t1, MyTable t2 
where t2.parent_id = t1.acc_id
  and t2.title = :TitleParameter
```

Depending upon Delphi DB-access library used (and there are many - https://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables/issues/98 ) the code would be something like this:

```
Var qGetParent: TSqlQuery;

.....

begin
  if nil = qGetParent then begin
     qGetParent := TSqlQuery.Create( MySQLConnection );
     qGetParent.SQL.Text := 'select...'; // see above
     qGetParent.Prepared := true;        // make SQL server compile this query only once
  end;

  qGetParent.Params[0].AsString := '1200'; 
    // we only have one parameter, so somewhat slow .ParamByName can easily be skipped  

  qGetParent.Open;
  while not qGetParent.EOF do begin
    // listing 0 or 1 or many rows returned by the query


    qGetParent.Next;
  end;
  qGetParent.Close; 
end;
```

---

Granted, it is hard to understand why you may ever need a query like this. Where do you take "1200" form ? from a program. But the program - like the tree on your screenshot - already know which `acc_id` value is set for the row where title is `1200` !!! You already have the data in the program about tree.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to guess which node would fit most as a parent? Well:

```
with recursive a (n) as (
  select cast(:N as varchar(30)) from rdb$database
  union all
  select
    case
      when n containing ' ' then left(n,char_length(n)-position(' ',reverse(n)))
      when char_length(n)=1 then 'Base'
      else left(n,char_length(n)-1)
    end
  from a
  where char_length(n)>=1 and n<>'Base')
select ac.acc_id,ac.acc_number
from a
  join accounts ac on ac.acc_number=rpad(a.n,4,'0')
fetch first 1 row only
```